# The result of a cell gets displayed in other cell

Tags: ios

I am developing an IOS App. A row consists of an TextField and some textviews. When the value of TextField is changed for any row the number in the TextField should be multiplied with the number in a Label og the same row and displayed in another Label in the same row. What actually happens is that the values are multiplied with the labels of another cell which is apparently random.

[image].

The image shows what is actually happening. This problem has me sorely puzzled for days and I am at my wits end.

I Tried Fetching Row From Tableview using didSelectRowAtIndex and 
indexPath.row.The Result Are are confusing as row index of first Two rows is being Showns as 0.

IndexPath correct in cellForRowAtIndexPath but is wrong in Textfield Method [ - (void) changedvalue: (UITextField *)textfield ]. What Could Be Worng ?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

//Code

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return _fetchedobj.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }
        data = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        _quantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f,28.0f,50.0f , 30.0f)];
        [_quantity setTag:indexPath.row];
        [_quantity setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
        [_quantity setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        _quantity.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [_quantity setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [_quantity addTarget:self action:@selector(changedvalue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];
        NSString *q_value = [data valueForKey:@"quantity"];
        NSInteger q_value1 = [q_value integerValue];
        [_quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)q_value1]];
        [cell addSubview:_quantity];

           _total1 = [[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 58.0f, 80.0f, 25.0f)];
        [_total1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
        [_total1 setTag:1];
        [_total1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_total1 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        _total1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSString *totalAmount = [data valueForKey:@"amount"];
        NSInteger total_Amount = [totalAmount integerValue];
        [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)total_Amount]];
        [cell addSubview:_total1];

    - (void) changedvalue: (UITextField *)textfield
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[textfield tag]);
        NSString *text = [textfield text];
        NSInteger text1 = [text integerValue];
        NSString *changevalue =  [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases_per_user"];
        NSInteger valueChange =  [changevalue integerValue];
        NSString *userPurchase = [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases"];
        NSInteger itemPurchase = [userPurchase integerValue];
        NSString *amount =  [data valueForKey:@"amount"];
        NSInteger amount1 = [amount integerValue];
        NSInteger minValue=MIN(valueChange, itemPurchase);
        if (text1 > minValue) {
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[textfield tag] inSection:0];
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         //   UITextField * field=cell.subviews[1];

       //     field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",minValue * amount1];
            NSLog(@"%@",cell);

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",minValue * amount1];

            //[_quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)minValue]];
            //[ _total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",minValue * amount1]];
        }else{
            [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",text1 * amount1]];
        }
        //    NSString *Amount =[data valueForKey:@"amount"];
        //    NSNumber *aNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[Amount integerValue]];
        //
        //    [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",([i integerValue] * [aNum integerValue])]];
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using properties to store your text field and label references and the adding these to your cell objects - which means that the "last" cell's objects will be in the properties. Also, when cells are re-used you are adding another label and text field.  You should create a UITableViewCell subclass and manage the text field/label via this subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You urgently need to take into account that cells are *reused*. That's what the "dequeueWithReuseIdentifier" does. So if you have 100 rows, and there are up to 10 visible at a time, you will have 10 rows using the same cell.

You must absolutely NOT create new textfields when dequeueWithReuseIdentifier doesn't return nil. It returns a cell that has already all the textfields created for it, from the previous time that the cell was used for a different or the same row.

And using indexPath.row as the index is a recipe for disaster if the user can add or remove rows. Say you are displaying row 10, then I delete row 8. Your cell now is in row 9, but has a tag that says row 10.